# Angular controller not working after loading in dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is a page I'm attempting to load in dynamically. I am able to verify that the manolisApp object is getting created, but the controller is not running. Is there something I'm missing or does it have an issue with being loaded in dynamically?

**HTML page I am loading in by ajax and inserting into a container:**

```
<div class="row" ng-app="manolisApp">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <!--<li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        <div ng-controller="LVController" style="display: none;">
            <div class="lv-group" ng-repeat="group in groups" id="{{group.id}}">
                <div class="page-header"><h2>{{group.name}}</h2></div>
                <div class="lv-unit" ng-repeat="unit in group.units track by $index" id="{{unit.serial}}-{{unit.tank_num}}-{{unit.bin_num}}">
                    <p><strong>{{unit.alias}}</strong></p>
                    <div class="graphic" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <p class="small">Type: {{unit.dev_type}}</p>
                    <p class="small">Serial Number: {{unit.serial}}</p>
                    <div class="extra-info"></div>
                    <p class="small" style="clear: both;">{{unit.reading[0].date}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var manolisApp = angular.module('manolisApp', []);
manolisApp.controller('LVController', function LVController($scope, $http) {
    var local_url = api_path+'/GetGroups/?username='+user;
    $http.get(local_url).then(function(GetGroups) {
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var manolisApp = angular.module('manolisApp', []);
manolisApp.controller('LVController',['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    var local_url = api_path+'/GetGroups/?username='+user;
    $http.get(local_url).then(function(GetGroups) {
        ...
    });
}]);
</script>
```

inject `'$scope','$http'` services to your controller.

also, remove `LVController` after function keyword. see if it works

Comment: That didn't help. The controller is still not running.

Comment: any console errors ? Also, why `style="display: none;"` ?

Comment: I remove the display: none when the content is loaded after the $http request to hide the ugly angular js template.

Comment: Also no console errors and not even console.log('testing') inside the controller feeds anything to the console

Comment: see this plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/uXUFeSVyeLKeE6opBMPC?p=preview
It is working fine here

Comment: That isn't the same thing. Your example is being loaded in an iframe. Mine is being dynamically loaded into a <div> container on a preloaded page.

Comment: The code I have *does* work fine when loaded prior to the DOM loading. But afterward the controllers don't want to run.